# Firebase Signup function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a function called signup that add a user to my firebase database with javascript in my web project. My function work well but when I want to redirect to another page at the end of the function, it doesn't add the user to my database. In the bottom code, if I remove the if statement, everything work perfectly but with it, it does redirect to the index page but doesn't add the user.

```
    function signup() {
        var UserEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var UserPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var errorCode = null;
        var errorMessage = null;       
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail,UserPassword).catch(function (error) {
                // Handle Errors here.
                errorCode = error.code;
                errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage);
            });

            if (errorCode == null) {
                window.location = '/index.html';
            }
        }
```

Comment: function signup() {
    var UserEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var UserPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var errorCode = null;
    var errorMessage = null;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        errorCode = error.code;
        errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

    if (errorCode == null) {
        window.location = '/index.html';
    }
}

Comment: Instead of adding information to your question in a comment, just edit the entire question to show the updates.

Answer (score 0):

> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...)

is returning a Future. So, the code inside your catch-function will be called asynchronously.

As a result, the following code

```
if (errorCode == null) {
      window.location = '/index.html';
}
```

may be called, before you even retreived an answer from your statement, since it is not in the error-block. At this time, errorCode is still null.

To solve this, you can access the 'then' callback of your function call:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail,UserPassword).then((userData) {
    //Redirect the user here
}).catch((error) {
    //Your Error-Handling
});
```